# php for all pages starting from "shop"

Tags: php, regex

I'm using following code in order to identify a perticular page in php.

```
  $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
  if($actual_link == "http://abcd.com/shop/")){
  //do some thing
  }
```

But this works only if the $actual_link is exactly same to http://abcd.com/shop/. How can make the if clause true for all the pages which 
is starting from "http://abcd.com/shop/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this (without regex):

```
// current on:
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

// if this page comes from:
$site = "http://abcd.com/shop/";

// do them start equal?
if ( substr($actual_link, 0, strlen($site)) == $site) {
     // yes? So, do something..
}
```

..